# How do I find the remaining space on an External Drive?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, storage

Through terminal on Linux, what exactly would I type to find External HDDs and their remaining storage space?

Comment: you can use df -h

Comment: Thanks you Scandalist, your help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: @Scandalist - Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, however the site's defined reason for the button is: "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or *not useful* (click again to undo)" (emphasis added).

Comment: Windows OS > WinSCP > select everything > Properties. Sorry, but I have tried all variations of df after being told that my drive was full and found that every answer returned was completely and totally inaccurate, and that I actually have plenty of free space on both by main drive and the USB drive.

Answer (score 9):

Linux doesn't differentiate between external and internal drives in any obvious way* – so you'll need to get a bit sneaky to get what you want.

Let's start with the most common scenario – you're running a desktop Linux install, and the drive was mounted for you by some helper program – in which case your drive might have a mount point that looks like `/media/username/disklabel/`.

If you mounted it manually, you'd know the location – and generally this would be under `/media/` or, if you're doing it old-school, `/mnt/`.

So, if you start with:

```
df -h
```

… which would give you Disk Free, Human readable, and filtered the output to any entry whose `Mounted on` column pointed at an obvious location for external drives, like `/media/`, you have a good chance of finding the amount of disk free for just your external drives.

<sub>* On some older kernels, with the older ATA driver, PATA hard drives were denoted by  `/dev/hdX` and most other drives were treated as SCSI drives with a `/dev/sdX` designation. On a system with no SCSI or SATA drives, there was a good chance external USB drives would be under `/dev/sdX`. Modern kernels however treat everything as a SCSI drive.</sub>